# Getting exception when clicking table view row

Tags: ios

I am parsing a json url and loading UITableview,I am clicking a row and navigating to other view.When 
I am returning to the main view and again clicking a row,I am having exception,please help.All array for populating tableview are allocated inside  viewWillAppear,and array elements are added

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    locArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    descArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    contArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    infoArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    addArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    typeArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    bigimgArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    imgArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    nameArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    catArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _res_lbl.hidden=YES;
    self.mytable_view.hidden=YES;
    TopPaidAppsFeed =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ami/activities.php?type=%@",urlconstant,self.type];

      NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TopPaidAppsFeed]];
      self.appListFeedConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
        NSAssert(self.appListFeedConnection != nil, @"Failure to create URL connection.");

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LazyTableCell";

    SimplecellCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[SimplecellCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSUInteger nodeCount = [self.entries count];
    if (nodeCount > 0)
    {
       // NSLog(@"NodeCount================%d",nodeCount);
        AppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        nameLblsize=[self sizeOfText:appRecord.name widthOfTextView:222 withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:15] ];

        CGRect cell_name_fr = cell.nameLbl.frame;
        cell_name_fr.size.height =nameLblsize.height;
        cell.nameLbl.frame = cell_name_fr;
        cell_name_fr.origin.y = (cell.frame.size.height-nameLblsize.height)/2;
        cell.nameLbl.text = appRecord.name;
        //cell.nameLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        NSLog(@"[locArr addObject:appRecord.location]===%@",appRecord.location);
        [locArr addObject:appRecord.location];
        [descArr addObject:appRecord.desc];
        [contArr addObject:appRecord.contacts];
        [nameArr addObject:appRecord.name];
        [infoArr addObject:appRecord.additional_info];
        [addArr addObject:appRecord.address];
        [imgArr addObject:appRecord.image];
        [bigimgArr addObject:appRecord.big_image];
        [catArr addObject:appRecord.categories];


        if (!appRecord.appIcon)
        {
            if (self.mytable_view.dragging == NO && self.mytable_view.decelerating == NO)
            {
                [self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            imgvwHeight=((10+nameLblsize.height+10+30)/2)-(53/2);
            [cell.imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, imgvwHeight, 62,53)];
            cell.imgView.image = appRecord.appIcon;

        }
    }

    return cell;

 }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    Event *listingNav=[[Event alloc]initWithNibName:@"Event" bundle:nil];

    listingNav.loc=[locArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//exception here
    listingNav.desc=[descArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    listingNav.contact=[contArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    listingNav.info=[infoArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    listingNav.name=[nameArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    listingNav.address=[addArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    listingNav.image=[imgArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    listingNav.big_image=[bigimgArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     listingNav.type=[catArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:listingNav animated:NO];
}
```

Exception is: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the 6th element element of your items array while it has only 5 elements. Also in your code there are tableView delegate methods missing like: `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` so you must getting a lot of warnings too.

At a glance it seems that your code is not able to parse what you expect it to parse from the request response.

Put breakpoints to see what you get in the response, make sure that your objects are added in the array and implement all the appropriate delegate methods of the UITableView class.

Comment: I have numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Ok. You are returning the wrong array count there. What is the entries array? After parsing the response you add each element in a different array. So all your arrays have one item. Tapping on the sixth cell with your current code looks for `[array objectAtIndex:6]` which does not exist, so you get a crash.

Comment: yes entries is that array which stores all elements after parsing

Answer (score 0):

Please check your result array count in Number of Rows in Section Method.If it is write try with some static array.